# JavaFX center two buttons below each other

Tags: button, javafx

I am new to JavaFX. Does anyone know how I can position two buttons vertically (below each other) in the middle of the screen.

This is my code so far:

```
public class StartMenu {
private StackPane gridStartMenu;
private Button createNewTournamentbtn;
private Button viewTournamentbtn;
private Scene startMenuScene;
private VBox vboxStartMenu;

public StartMenu() {
    gridStartMenu = new StackPane();
    vboxStartMenu = new VBox();

    //BUTTON 1
    createNewTournamentbtn = new Button("Create new tournament");
    createNewTournamentbtn.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    createNewTournamentbtn.setPrefSize(300, 50);

    //BUTTON 2
    viewTournamentbtn = new Button("View tournaments");
    viewTournamentbtn.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
    viewTournamentbtn.setPrefSize(300, 50);

    gridStartMenu.setAlignment(createNewTournamentbtn, Pos.CENTER);
    gridStartMenu.setAlignment(viewTournamentbtn, Pos.CENTER);


    gridStartMenu.getChildren().addAll(createNewTournamentbtn,
            viewTournamentbtn);

    startMenuScene = new Scene(gridStartMenu, 600, 600);
    MainApp.getWindow().setScene(startMenuScene);
    MainApp.getWindow().show();
```

Comment: Have you used the JavaFX Scenebuilder?

Comment: No haven't used Scenebuilder

Comment: If you're using Eclipse you might consider it.  It will allow you do drag/drop buttons, dropdowns, etc.

Comment: Oke sounds good. I will have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you use a Rapid Application Development (RAD) tool such as SceneBuilder, you still need to understand the layout panes that it helps you create. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kind advice: Do not rely on Scenebuilder or such stuff too much. If you really want to learn JavaFX, code entirely by yourself.

And this is how you can do what you want to do:

First, add two buttons into [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html):

```
VBox vbox = new VBox(5); // 5 is the spacing between elements in the VBox
vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Button("Button 1"), new Button("Button 2"));
```

Afterwards, center the VBox using the following code:

```
stackPane.getChildren().add(vbox);
StackPane.setAlignment(vbox, Pos.CENTER);
stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane));
stage.show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked:). Also thanks for your advice. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

First , I'd like to mention some of advantages of FXML :

check the link [Why use FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm#CHDIEGBB)

Implementation by using FXML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-base: #b6e7c9;;" text="Create new tournament">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-base: #b6e7c9;" text="View tournaments">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwRuw.png)